# How to slice an array of tuples with numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-slicing

I have a numpy array of tuples:

```
>>> v.dtype
dtype([('AgentID', '<i8'), ('CellID', '<i4'), ('Hybridization', '<f4')])
```

Is there an way to create an array containing only the 'Hybridization' values, without looping through the tuples in v?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not an array of tuples (which would be a pretty useless data structure). [That is a structured array](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.rec.html). You can get the values you want simply by:

```
arr['Hybridization']
```

For example:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: arr = np.array([(1,2,3),(4,5,6), (7,8,9)], dtype=np.dtype([('AgentID', '<i8'), ('CellID', '<i4'), ('Hybridization', '<f4')]))

In [3]: arr['Hybridization']
Out[3]: array([3., 6., 9.], dtype=float32)
```